# Jquery .ajax posting to itself instead of script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, post

I have a form:

```
 <form name="emailform" id="emailform" onsubmit="emailSubmit()" method="post"><div>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
        <input class="btn" type=submit value="Submit"></div>
            </form>
```

Here's emailSubmit():

```
    function emailSubmit(){
         $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "mysitesip/addemail.php",
                      data: {
                            email: $("#email").val()
                        },
                      success: function (data) {
                            $('#success').html(data);

                      }
                    });  // end Ajax    
    }
```

When I click on the submit buton, it posts, with the email address as a parameter, to itself, instead of addemail.php, and the page refreshes? Why is this happening? If I get rid of the method="post", then the form puts out a GET request to itself, but with with correct email as a parameter. This is extremely confusing to me, because the .ajax method clearly states that the type is POST. Why would changing the "method" of the form alter the posting for emailSubmit()?

The .ajax call was taken verbatim from an EXTREMELY similar usage on another one of my pages, where it works fine.

(When I say "it is POSTing" or "it is GETing", I am using firebug to see these things)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing nothing to cancel the standard form submission.

The net result is that the Ajax stuff submits to the URI you specify, then the form submits as normal (to the URI of the current page because you forgot the `action` attribute).

1. Stop using intrinsic event attributes (i.e. the onsubmit attribute)
2. Use JS [event binding](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) instead
3. [prevent the default submit action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
4. Make sure that you have an action attribute pointing at a sensible place so if the JS fails for any reason, the form still works. c.f. [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Or, as a quick and dirty hack … `return false` at the end of the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: I did this: $("#emailform").submit(
   function emailSubmit(){...}); Including ending the function with a return false. And got rid of the onsubmit attribute. But nothing changed. Why?

Comment: (in the meantime, i just returned the onsubmit, which worked, for others who are also having this problem)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false so the form doesn't submit, and return the value in the handler:

```
onsubmit="return emailSubmit()"
```

And:

```
function emailSubmit(){
     $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "mysitesip/addemail.php",
                  data: {
                        email: $("#email").val()
                    },
                  success: function (data) {
                        $('#success').html(data);

                  }
                });  // end Ajax    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That won't work. The event handler doesn't do anything with the return value from the `emailSubmit` function.

Comment: You're right, looked at it too quickly. Edited as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp - "A submit button is used to send form data to a server."

What I do is the following -

```
 <form name="emailform" id="emailform" method="post"><div>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
    <input class="btn" type=button onclick="emailSubmit()"></div>
 </form>
```

---

***Edit,*** as was pointed out my original posting will not work.  The post I should have made -

```
 <form name="emailform" id="emailform" ><div>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
      </div>
 </form>
 <input class="btn" type=button onclick="emailSubmit()">
```

I just verified that pressing enter doesn't do a submit and the answer is consistent with my current code base.

Comment: Pressing enter in the text input will still submit the form as normal. That is too fragile a solution.

Comment: You are correct.  I copied too quickly.  I don't use the method attribute

Comment: Adding a method attribute won't stop enter in a text input submitting the form as normal.